# Class Attributes Being Overwritten in @Html.ActionLink for my ASP.NET MVC App

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following link in a Details View:

```
@Html.ActionLink(linkText:"Edit",actionName:"Edit",controllerName:"Profile",routeValues:new { id = Model.Id },htmlAttributes:new { @class = "btn btn-primary"})
```

The link is being rendered as:

```
<a class="active" href="/Profile/Edit/2">Edit</a>
```

I would like the link to render as:

```
<a class="active btn btn-primary" href="/Profile/Edit/2">Edit</a>
```

What am I doing wrong? What should I do?

Comment: Where is the class "active" coming from?

Comment: That's what I am wondering.

Comment: Is "active" even a valid class in your CSS?

Comment: You're sure this is _exactly_ the text of the line in your Details view? And you haven't created your own `ActionLink` extension method?  _And_, the word "active" isn't used elsewhere in your view or controller?

Comment: I think active is defined in bootstrap 4

Comment: Ah. Unfortunately, I can't help any further: I'm not familiar with Bootstrap!

Comment: ok, I hope there will still be someone to help.

Comment: Just add ``active`` to: ``@class = "active btn btn-primary"``. That should render: ``<a class="active btn btn-primary" href="/Profile/Edit/2">Edit</a>``

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working as:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { controller = "Profile", id = Model.Id }, htmlAttributes:new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
```